# R t-test comparing two proportions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have two populations

population 1:
n=160, male=14, female=146

population 2:
n=150, male=16, female=134

How can I test if the two populations are significantly different?

I guess I have to use a t-test for two proportions, but I don't know how to do this with R

Comment: Cross Validated isn’t the place to ask implementation questions (that’s the original Stack Overflow), but there’s some statistical content here to cover. Chiefly, what is the exact phrasing of your homework problem? (And if this is indeed homework, please add the self-study tag.) If you have a population, then “statistical significance” no longer applies.

Answer (score 3):

Hypothesis tests are for making an inference about populations from samples drawn from them, e.g. to see whether two population proportions ($\pi_1,\pi_2$) differ, i.e. $\pi_1\neq \pi_2$ when you can only observe sample proportions $p_1$ and $p_2$ for random samples drawn from those populations of interest.

> I have two populations

If you have the populations you're wanting to make some assertion about, there's *nothing* to infer. You just look at the proportions, since you're observing $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ directly. Either they're equal or they aren't.

Note also that if you treat your population as a sample but you use the finite population correction (as you should), when you observe the whole population (i.e. your sample is a census), the standard error of the proportion goes to 0, and the result is the same -- you just look at the proportions and if they're -even slightly- different, you will reject.

[If this seems off to you because tiny differences aren't meaningful, then a typical hypothesis test was not the right tool to begin with, even if you had a small sample.]

Also note that a t-test isn't the most usual way to compare proportions. In general it should work reasonably well, but usually something based off the fact that this is count data (or an asymptotic approximation of that) is used.